# Cómo cambiar el propietario de la cuenta a Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: vsts

He iniciado un proyecto en Visual Studio Team services con una cuenta asociada a mi correo electrónico personal, ahora quiero cambiar el correo electrónico propietario de esta cuenta para el correo electrónico de mi cliente, ¿qué hago?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz ¡Gracias por la atención!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acceda a su proyecto

> https://{tucuenta}.visualstudio.com/_projects

- Haga clic en el icono del engranaje
- Clic en Setting
- Haga clic en Change (Current owner)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]